# Correct usage of _writev in node.js

Tags: node.js, node-streams

What is the correct usage of `_writev()` in node.js?
The documentation says:

> If a stream implementation is capable of processing multiple chunks of data at once, the `writable._writev()` method should be implemented.

It also says:

> The primary intent of `writable.cork()` is to avoid a situation where writing many small chunks of data to a stream do not cause a backup in the internal buffer that would have an adverse impact on performance. In such situations, implementations that implement the `writable._writev()` method can perform buffered writes in a more optimized manner.

From a stream implementation perspective this is okay. But from a writable stream consumer perspective, the only way that `write` or `writev` gets invoked is through `Writable.write()` and `writable.cork()`

**I would like to see a small example which would depict the practical use case of implementing `_writev()`**

Comment: "The writable._writev() method is prefixed with an underscore because it is internal to the class that defines it, and should never be called directly by user programs."  https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_writev_chunks_callback

Comment: When you implement a stream _write and _writev are the primary functions that need to be implemented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `writev` method can be added to the instance, in addition to `write`, and if the streams contains several chunks that method will be picked instead of `write`. For example Elasticsearch allows you to bulk insert records; so if you are creating a Writable stream to wrap Elasticsearch, it makes sense to have a `writev` method doing a single bulk insert rather than several individual ones, it is far more efficient. The same holds true, for example, for MongoDB and so on.

This post (not mine) shows an Elasticsearch implementation https://medium.com/@mark.birbeck/using-writev-to-create-a-fast-writable-stream-for-elasticsearch-ac69bd010802

Comment: I'm relatively new to Nodejs Streams (in a more complex use-case). This answer has helped me A LOT! Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 1):

The `_writev()` will been invoked when using `uncork()`. There is a simple example in node document.

```
stream.cork();
stream.write('some ');
stream.write('data ');
process.nextTick(() => stream.uncork());
```

More See,

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_uncork
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_writable.js#L257

Comment: This is not an example _writev usage, it is an example of using cork / uncork

Comment: you can just define it like _write. see https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v8.11.1/lib/_stream_writable.js#L395

Comment: You keep missing the point - OP asked for "a small example which would depict the PRACTICAL use case ...", not an explanation of how it works or a link to the documentation. I have added an answer more in line with my reading of their question

Comment: Nice work! I thought it's easy to use _write example, just replace _write to _writev